# Based on the column values add a row value to the column in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table as below:

[image]

I want the result as displayed only when the col1 and col2 values are same in the two rows.

Can anyone provide the SQL query, please?

Comment: What is the rule? What if Col4 is also filled? What if there are 3 rows?

Comment: if col4 is filled replace with the col3 value from the second row

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide the details so I will suggest the following solution with pivoting:

```
with cte as(select col1, 
                   col2, 
                   col3, 
                   row_number() over(partition by col1, col2 order by col3) rn 
            from tablename)
select col1, col2, [1] as col3, [2] as col4
from cte
pivot(max(col3) for rn in([1],[2]))p
```